# Create a new array that counts how many time a certain parameter occures in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array that gives some extra paramters which contain product data. I recreated a simple version for this which looks like this:

```
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world'
        tags: [{id: 1, tagName: 'prices'}, {id: 2, tagName: 'video'}]
    },
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world'
        tags: [{id: 3, tagName: 'images'}, {id: 2, tagName: 'video'}]
    },
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world'
        tags: [{id: 2, tagName: 'video'}, {id: 4, tagName: 'site'}, {id: 6, tagName: 'online'}]
    }
]
```

This each object in my array has an array called  "tags". I have to create a new array that looks through this array and counts how many times a certain tag is used on a product so I can create a result that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        amount: 3
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        amount: 1
    }
]
```

---

What I did so far was create an empty array and start looping through the product array. Then I check if the tag.id is found within my new array, if not.. then add it to the array. If the loop would find the same Id again, instead of adding a new item to the array it should increase the amount by 1.

So far I think I'm really over engineering it since I can't get this to work properly. Maybe someone here can help me with some code I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably faster ways, but this is one way to do it:

```js
const original = [
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world',
        tags: [{id: 1, tagName: 'prices'}, {id: 2, tagName: 'video'}]
    },
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world',
        tags: [{id: 3, tagName: 'images'}, {id: 2, tagName: 'video'}]
    },
    {
        title: 'hello',
        description: 'world',
        tags: [{id: 2, tagName: 'video'}, {id: 4, tagName: 'site'}, {id: 6, tagName: 'online'}]
    }
];

let tags = [];

original.forEach(e => {
    e.tags.forEach(t => {
        let match = tags.find(tag => tag.id == t.id);
        if (match) {
            match.amount++;
        } else {
            tags.push({id: t.id, amount: 1});
        }
    });
});

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Map Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to count the tags.

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'world',
    tags: [
      { id: 1, tagName: 'prices' },
      { id: 2, tagName: 'video' },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'world',
    tags: [
      { id: 3, tagName: 'images' },
      { id: 2, tagName: 'video' },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'world',
    tags: [
      { id: 2, tagName: 'video' },
      { id: 4, tagName: 'site' },
      { id: 6, tagName: 'online' },
    ],
  },
];

const map = new Map();
data.forEach(({ tags }) => {
  tags.forEach(({ id }) => {
    const key = id;
    if (map.has(key))
      map.set(key, { ...map.get(key), amount: map.get(key).amount + 1 });
    else map.set(key, { id, amount: 1 });
  });
});
const ret = [...map.values()];
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Oh I didn't knew about the map functionality. I will study that! Thanks for your answer it helped alot!